# Golang - how this func is called

Tags: go

I'm working with [this sample](https://github.com/ronnyhartenstein/golang-csv-parallel-processing/blob/dd4e75737c18fa6877a4a515074474a58555376a/import/import.go#L47) code but cannot understand how this function is called and which parameter is belong.

```
go func(r []string) {
    processData(r)
    ch <- r
}(record)
```

Comment: did you try the documentation? https://golang.org/doc

Comment: could you give a chapter name relative to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[function closures](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/25):

> Go functions may be closures. A closure is a function value that
>   references variables from outside its body. The function may access
>   and assign to the referenced variables; in this sense the function is
>   "bound" to the variables.

To Understand this:

```
go func(r []string) {
    processData(r)
    ch <- r
}(record)
```

let's first declare this function:

```
func routine(r []string) {
    processData(r)
    ch <- r
}
```

and this global variable:

```
var ch = make(chan []string)
```

Now you may call it:

```
go routine(record)
```

this calls function named `routine` with input parameter named `record` as a goroutine.

And see: https://gobyexample.com/goroutines

Try it on [The Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/GSO8lMxIKT):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "time"
)

func routine(r []string) {
    processData(r)
    ch <- r
}

var ch = make(chan []string)

func main() {
    start := time.Now()
    flag.Parse()
    fmt.Print(strings.Join(flag.Args(), "\n"))
    if *filename == "REQUIRED" {
        return
    }

    csvfile, err := os.Open(*filename)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    defer csvfile.Close()

    reader := csv.NewReader(csvfile)

    i := 0
    for {
        record, err := reader.Read()
        if err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        i++

        go routine(record)

        fmt.Printf("go %d %s\n", i, record)
    }
    for ; i >= 0; i-- {
        fmt.Printf("<- %d %s\n", i, <-ch)
    }

    fmt.Printf("\n%2fs", time.Since(start).Seconds())

}

func processData([]string) {
    time.Sleep(10 * time.Millisecond)
}

var filename = flag.String("f", "REQUIRED", "source CSV file")
var numChannels = flag.Int("c", 4, "num of parallel channels")

//var bufferedChannels = flag.Bool("b", false, "enable buffered channels")
```

Comment: So should I understand it as non-name function with call immediatly like 'lambda'?

Comment: Yes, it is called function closures.